# node.js code to open a page in browser with localhost URL

Tags: html, node.js, url, browser, server

I have written a simple server using node.js. At the moment the server responds by writing "hello world" to the browser.

The server.js file looks like this:

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

I use this URL in the browser to trigger the "hello world" response:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

I want to be able to open a basic html page when I pass a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/test.html
```

I have looked through many tutorials and some stackoverflow posts but there was not much out there on this specific task. Does anyone know how to achieve this with a simple modification to the server.js file?

Comment: Does that help? [Open a URL via the operating system](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openurl)

Comment: Yes this may help, I'll look into it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn add express open
```

```js
import open from 'open';
import express from 'express';

const port = 3000;
const app = express();

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, Coder!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listen port: ${port}`);
  open(`http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```

Second variant:

```js
const http = require('http');
const open = require('open');

const PORT = 3000;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write('<h1>Hello World!</h1>');
  res.end();
}).listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
  
  // Open the server URL in the default browser
  open(`http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to open .html file through nodejs with the help of "http://localhost:8080/test.html" such url, you need to convert .html page to .jade format.Use rendering engine with the help of expressjs framework.Express rendering engine will help you to render .jade file on nodejs server.

Comment: Thats quite complicated, however, it may be the cleanest way to do it. I'll look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It is better to use a front end javascript frameworks such as Angular, React or Vue to route to different pages. Though, if you want to do it in Node, you could do something like this using express:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('views/index.html', { root: __dirname })
});
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('views/test.html', { root: __dirname })
});
app.listen(8080);
```

This is an ok solution for static pages. Express is very useful for writing REST API's.